# my iOS App crash very often with [UIGestureRecognizer _delegateShouldReceiveTouch:] of pan gesture

Tags: ios, events, touch, gesture

My iOS App crash very often at [UIGestureRecognizer _delegateShouldReceiveTouch:] with pan gesture. I am using pan gestures for the resizing and moving of a view. The view has multiple instances during the running of my App. Though crash happens very often, it can't be reproduced reliably. Here is the main part of the crash log.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x39de65b6 objc_msgSend + 22
1   UIKit                           0x33e4193e -[UIGestureRecognizer _delegateShouldReceiveTouch:] + 114
2   UIKit                           0x33d6f8b2 -[UITouchesEvent _addGestureRecognizersForView:toTouch:currentTouchMap:newTouchMap:] + 782
3   UIKit                           0x33d6f394 -[UITouchesEvent _addTouch:forDelayedDelivery:] + 212
4   UIKit                           0x33d6f2ac _AddTouchToEvent + 184
5   UIKit                           0x33d5d026 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5910
6   GraphicsServices                0x35a515a0 _PurpleEventCallback + 588
7   GraphicsServices                0x35a511ce PurpleEventCallback + 30
8   CoreFoundation                  0x31f2a170 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 32
9   CoreFoundation                  0x31f2a112 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134
10  CoreFoundation                  0x31f28f94 __CFRunLoopRun + 1380
11  CoreFoundation                  0x31e9beb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
12  CoreFoundation                  0x31e9bd44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
13  GraphicsServices                0x35a502e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
14  UIKit                           0x33db12fc UIApplicationMain + 1116
15  TestApp                             0x0008adb4 0x1c000 + 454068
16  TestApp                             0x0001e40c 0x1c000 + 9228
```

Does any one has a similiar experience of crashing at [UIGestureRecognizer _delegateShouldReceiveTouch:]?

Any hint, theory on how it would happen is appreciated.

Comment: Please insert some code

Comment: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error occurs when you release a deallocated object!
Check you pan gesture object carefully! :)

Comment: I would like to be able to insert some code here. The problem is I have no idea which part of the code base can be inserted here to be helpful. The crash happens with touch handling. But what exactly went wrong is unknown. It looks like this is a memory management problem. Is it possible that the gesture's delegate is deallocated at the time of touch handling?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the delegate that you assigned to the UIGestureRecognizer instance got deallocated. Hence the gesture recognizer will call a delegate method on an object that does not exist any more.

Make sure to set the delegate of the gesture recognizer to nil, when the object that is assigned as the delegate gets released. E.g. in the dealloc method.

Comment: Thanks. I am waiting for the test result.